# How to debug 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

There are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow related to this error. I’ve read some excellent posts on [how Optionals work](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/understanding-optionals-swift) and this [error in particular](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/understanding-the-fatal-error-cant-unwrap-optional-none-errors-in-swift/). However, I haven’t found any information about the best way to figure out which value is being set to nil and causing the error in the first place.

Are there any good debugging techniques to find out which Optional is causing this error?

Answer (score 34):

Here's at least half an answer (would the other respondents please read the question first!): Use the simulator instead of an actual iOS device.

The debugger seems to be pretty good at pointing to the line with the maltreated optional that's causing the trouble... unless you are like me, choosing to run the code on an iOS device directly from time to time. In the latter case, the debugger lands me right in the middle of some assembler code with no sensible stack trace. Switching back to the simulator gives the exact line of code at fault.

Comment: Thanks, that´s great. Good to know!

Comment: This is what I needed to know. I get *what* the problem is, but I needed to figure out *where* the problem is in order to fix it, and none of the breakpoints I've been setting while blindly guessing had been hit.

Comment: Worked for me. Xcode is such ass sometimes... Is there a technical reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You Xcode does not crash at the incorrect line of code?

This does not response to the question but it's important to note:

```
When you are not sure about an optional variable, you have to verify if it contains value or not, by using a pattern like this:

var myOptional : String?
if let aString = myOptional {
    //do your work with aString.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What basically optional value is "?" when you place ? after a datatype that is optional while if it is unwrapped and a nil appears theres no error but it you place "!" exclamation mark after datatype then if it unwrap the variable and nil appears then there's crash or error so often use optional as

```
var myVariable : DataType ? = DataType()
or 
var myVariable : DataType ? = nil
or
var myVariable : DataType ? = value
```

An optional in Swift is a variable that can hold either a value or no value. Optionals are written by appending a ? to the type:

```
var myOptionalString:String? = "Hello"
```

Some places optionals are useful:

- When a property can be there or not there, like middleName or spouse
  in a Person class
- When a method can return a value or nothing, like
  searching for a match in an array
- When a method can return either a    result or get an error and
  return nothing
- Delegate properties (which    don't always have to be    set)
- For    weak properties in classes. The    thing they point to can
  be set    to nil
- For a large resource that might    have to be    released    to
  reclaim memory

https://medium.com/@rrridges/swift-optionals-a10dcfd8aab5